# Python thread synchronisation

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I have 3 tasks : t1, t2 and t3.
I want to run t1 and t2 in two parallels threads. And I want to wait for the end of t1 and t2 execution before running t3.

t1 =========> |
t2 ====>           |
t3......................|=======>
-------------------------------------------------------------(time)-->

I have some basis about threads synchronization but I can't find out how to manage with this case.
Is there any build-in solution in python library did I have to write a my own (semaphore based ?) solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wait on threads with [`join`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

```
# start the two threads
t1.start()
t2.start()

# wait until both ended
t1.join()
t2.join()

# then start the third
t3.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to have a look at the module [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html). It provides [lock objects](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects), [condition objects](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#condition-objects) and [semaphore objects](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects).